# unable to pass parameter from azure Devops yaml to PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

```
parameters:
- name: AzureSubscription
  default: 'abc'
- name: BlobName
  type: string
  default: ""
stages:
- stage: MyStage
  displayName: 'My Stage'
  variables:
    - name: sas

 jobs:
   - job: ABC
     displayName: ABC 
     steps:
     - task: AzureCLI@2
       displayName: 'XYZ'
       inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.AzureSubscription }}
        scriptType: pscore
        arguments: 
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          $sas=az storage account generate-sas --account-key "mykey" --account-name "abc" --expiry (Get-Date).AddHours(100).ToString("yyyy-MM-dTH:mZ") --https-only --permissions rw --resource-types sco --services b
          Write-Host "My Token: " $sas

    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'filepath'
        filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/psscript.ps1
        arguments: >
          -Token "????"
          -BlobName "${{parameters.BlobName}}"
        displayName: 'some work'
```

In this Azure Devops yaml, i have created 2 tasks.  AzureCLI@2 and PowerShell@2

In AzureCLI@2  i get value in $sas varaible. Write-Host confirms that, but $sas does not get passes as parameter to PowerShell@2 powershell file as parameter.

"${{parameters.BlobName}}" is working fine. In powershell i am able to read that value.
How to pass sas variable value?
Tried

-Token $sas    # not worked

-Token "${{sas}}"    # not worked

Answer (score 0):

Different tasks in Azure Pipeline don't share a common runspace that would allow them to preserve or pass on variables.

For this reason Azure Pipelines offers special logging commands that allow to take string output from a task to update an Azure Pipeline environment variable that can be used in subsequent tasks: [Set variables in scripts (Microsoft Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts).

In your case you would use a logging command like this to make your sas token available to the next task:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sas]$sas"
```

In the argument of your subsequent task (within the same job) use the variable syntax of Azure Pipelines:

```
-Token '$(sas)'
```